# Xubuntu 16.04: Deactivate suggestions/auto-complete in save file dialog

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gtk, dialog

When saving files, especially from the browser, I keep encountering the following problem:

Often the file name contain a prefix that I want to remove. To do this, I switch to the beginning of the file name with <kbd>Home</kbd> and delete the unnecessary characters with <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Unfortunately, this causes the auto-completion of the file dialog to become active:

- If there are a lot of files in the current folder (like in my Downloads folder) the complete dialog freezes briefly.
- It has often happened that parts of the suggestion have been inserted into my file name or that the suggestion has completely replaced my file name (maybe also influenced by the delay).

I'm working with XUbuntu 16.04 LTS. This is what the problem looks like:

[image: This is what the problem looks like]

**Is there a way to disable this auto-completion or suggestion of file names in the save file dialog?** Ideally, this would not affect the file open dialog. I already searched about settings of `gtk.FileChooserDialog` that can be changed using

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser ...
```

but didn't found any suitable settings listed by `list-keys`.

Comment: FYI: Xubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://xubuntu.org/release/16-04/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` on your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Xubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: Thanks. A change to a newer version or even a different distribution would be too much time effort for me at the moment, so I would like to stay with this version for the time being.